# References not showing in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I am using main body in my latex document and this does not include references in the table of content.

This is the main body.
[image]

Then in table of content I have something like this:

[image]

No references. I had the same problem with appendix but I just used addcontentsline at the begging of the appendix and it works. But in case of the references the document where references are saved as .bib document and can't do the same. Is there any solution to that?

[image]

Comment: First, a general comment: Please post actual LaTeX code, *not* screenshots of LaTeX code. Second, have you considered inserting the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` immediately before the `\bibliography` directive?

Comment: Second one worked. Thanks a lot Mico.

Comment: Can I do the same for list of figures and tables. I am using this command for them: \tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

Comment: The answer is "yes".